# Parsing Google ignoring the Error using JSOUP

Tags: java

I am working on a simple crawler. I can parse google using jsoup, no problem. But sometimes crawling some word gives error.I like the jsoup not to stop but ignore the error and keep giving me the output. I tried like following but it gives the same result as the google result is always same. Please give me a solution.

```
String GOOGLE_SEARCH_URL = "https://www.google.com/search";
String searchURL = GOOGLE_SEARCH_URL + "?q=" + word + "&num=" + 4;
for(int m =0; m <4;m++){
    try {
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect(searchURL).userAgent("Mozilla/5.0").get();
        Elements results = doc.select("h3.r > a");
        ..........
        .........
        }
    catch (HttpStatusException e) {
        continue;
    }
}
```

Result:

```
conn built
Success
Enter a word

far
http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/far
Count of [far] is : 71
http://www.farmanager.com/
Count of [far] is : 7
.....repeat
```

If I don't use try catch the error is:

```
http://www.thefreedictionary.com/far
Exception in thread "main" org.jsoup.HttpStatusException: HTTP error       fetching URL. Status=403, URL=http://www.thefreedictionary.com/_/403.aspx?p
..........
```

**to be honest, I don't like to use for loop but is there any way just ignore some site and keep giving me the results?**

Comment: What are you attempting to do? Scrape Google or visit pages of search results? And where does `word` come from? From user input? Might need to edit out the ellipsis (...).

Comment: word is the search word. Here it is a string